# Arduino can't POST data to PHP

Tags: php, c, http, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have written a code for my Arduino to read data from sensor and then `post` to a PHP file called `post-data.php`, which then the PHP will insert the data into a database.
However, my Arduino does not seemed to be able to `post` the data or it is not `post`ing it correctly.

```
#ifdef ESP32
  #include <WiFi.h>
  #include <HTTPClient.h>
#else
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
  #include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
  #include <WiFiClient.h>
  #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#endif

#define signalPin 12
#define sensorPin A0

const char *ssid = "****";
const char *password = "*****";
const char* serverName = "http://smartswitchfyp.rf.gd/post-data.php";
String apiKeyValue = "*******";
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);

  Serial.print("Configuring access point...");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFI connected");
  Serial.print("IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());


void loop() {
  if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
    HTTPClient http;

// Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
http.begin(serverName);

// Specify content-type header
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

sensor();
// Prepare your HTTP POST request data
String httpRequestData = "api_key=" + apiKeyValue + "&value1=" + String(current) + "&value2=" + String(power) + "";


//String httpRequestData = "api_key=******9&value1=24.75&value2=49.54";
//Serial.print("httpRequestData: ");
//Serial.println(httpRequestData);

int httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData);


if (httpResponseCode>0) {
  Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
  Serial.println(response);
}
else {
  Serial.print("Error code: ");
  Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
}
http.end();

  }
  else {
    Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

I have checked that my `serverName` is correct.

I have tested the `post-data.php`, and it works fine as there is an update at my database. Below is the test code, `test.php` I used to test `post-data.php`

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="post-data.php" method="post">
api: <input type="text" name="api_key">
Name: <input type="text" name="value1">
Email: <input type="text" name="value2">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And below is my `post-data.php` file

```
<?php

$servername = "sql101.epizy.com";
$dbname = "epiz_28338452_smartswitch";
$username = "epiz_28338452";
$password = "********";

// Keep this API Key value to be compatible with the ESP32 code provided in the project page. If you change this value, the ESP32 sketch needs to match
$api_key_value = "*******";

$api_key = $value1 = $value2 = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $api_key = test_input($_POST["api_key"]);
    if($api_key == $api_key_value) {
        $value1 = test_input($_POST["value1"]);
        $value2 = test_input($_POST["value2"]);
        
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Sensor (value1, value2) VALUES ('" . $value1 . "', '" . $value2 . "')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    
        $conn->close();
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong API Key provided.";
    }

}
else {
    echo "No data posted with HTTP POST.";
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

I'm 90% sure that is not the `post-data.php` file problem but my Arduino not able to `post` the data to the php file.
At my Arduino code, I used the line

```
http.begin(serverName);
```

to connect to the `post-data.php` and then prepare the header:

```
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

and prepare the content:

```
 String httpRequestData = "api_key=" + apiKeyValue + "&value1=" + String(current) + "&value2=" + String(power) + "";
```

where current and power is process in other function/method. I have tested the current and power output, and they are float variables. Finally I used the line

```
int httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData);
```

to `post` the 3 data to the php file.
When I startup the Arduino, the output shows `HTTP Response code: 200`, which I believe the php file was successfully called (correct me if I am wrong). However, my database does not have any data inserted. Again the `test.php` prove that the database can be inserted with data.
Below is image of the database value inserted by the `test.php` file

Can anyone help me as I'm not sure what cause the Arduino to not able to post the data. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Warning! You're open to SQL injection attacks and should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with bound parameters instead of injection user data directly into the database query like that. That old `test_input()` function is not sufficient protection for it (it's a very old legacy function that people should stop using, at least for escaping database values).

Comment: Check what PHP actually gets. Do a `var_dump($_SERVER, $_POST);` to see what the request looks like (method etc) and what values it posted, if any.

Comment: ** PLEASE REMOVE THE API KEY FROM YOUR POST. **

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for replying, I understand the vulnerability of the sql injection. But since this is just something i would like to test out on my own, I did not mind about the security issue yet. I'm more concerning on getting the data transfered.

As to check what the PHP get, i can't really test it directly from my arduino, because the php execution was called programmatically from my arduino, meaning there is no visual display (the php echo wont be display). 

May I ask if you know a way for the httpclient to get the PHP echo response?

Comment: You can log the request in a file: `file_put_contents('/path/to/file.log', json_encode(['server' => $_SERVER, 'post' => $_POST], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), FILE_APPEND);`. That line will append every request to the file you define so you can check it after the request has been made. Regarding SQL injections, it's not just about security. If any of your values would, for example, contain a single quote, your query would break.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for the help, i have manage to log the post value and it seemed like the arduino is not able to access the post-data.php url at all like norahCli mentioned below. I think I have to fix that first. and ill take note and change the sql prepare statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't access your infinity free site with your arduino because infinity free have a security system
see https://support.infinityfree.net/websites/what-is-the-i-1-suffix/ for more info

Comment: Hi norahCli, thanks for the reply. I have read the link you shared and it seemed like indeed my Arduino is not able to access the website at all. Although the link said it is not possible to remove the suffix without paying, mind if I ask if there is any way I can bypass that suffix, or is there any alternative free hosting service you recommend? I have tried 000webhost, but I decided not to use because the website loads too long.

Comment: well, freewha is a opinion but api sites are not allowed, they terminate them in 3 days or less, however you can access your database after termination. and premium plans don't have that limition you can use your site as api site if you pay 1$ monthly (paid yearly).  awardspace is a opinion too, i don't know their TOS. Or you can deploy your script to heroku, which is complicated if you do it for first time

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestions. I have tried awardspace and it seemed to be the best option for me so far. They have quite fast loading speed which is idea for my arduino. Thanks again!